# Android 10 wifi connection can't reach gateway

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, android-10.0

I try to make a simple app that connect the smartphone to a specify wifi network and redirect to a webview that show a webserver connected on the wifi network by flashing a QR Code.

When I flash my QR Code (Simple Wifi QR Code) the app ask if I want to connect to the wifi network, I confirm and then it redirect to a webview but the webview is blank... It looks like I'm connected to the wifi but I can't reach the network...

Part of my QR Code Activity :

```
public void successFlash(String ssid, String password) {

    WifiNetworkSpecifier specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
            .setSsid(ssid)
            .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
            .build();

    NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
            .build();

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


    ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                    openActivity_redirect_webview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnavailable() {
            // do failure processing here..
            openQrcodeActivity();
        }

    };
    connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback);
}
```

My webview Activity :

```
public class activity_redirect_webview extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_redirect_webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.redirect_webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.4.1/index.html");
  }
```

}

Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

**EDIT :** My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra with Android 10

I install a Network Analyzer app and it confirm that I'm not really connected to the wifi network.

Manualy connection to the wifi network :

[Screenshot Network Analyzer Manualy connected to wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vfo9.jpg)

Connection by scanning QR Code from My App :

[Screenshot Succes QR Code scan, confirm connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWYdY.jpg)

[Screenshot wifi settings actual network Connected via My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsZ9y.jpg)

[Screenshot Network Analyzer connected to wifi via My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ1E3.jpg)

As we can see it's look like i'm connected to the wifi network but it doesn't gives me ip address and I can't ping my web server...

Does I need more permissions in AndrooidManifest ??

I don't understand why when I use my app to connect to a wifi network i got this problem... I try with others wifi network and it's the same.
I'm totally stuck and I found no solution on forums...

Comment: Try to load that url in a browser on your phone.

Comment: You cannot use the http:// protocol unless you request clearTextTraffic in manifest file.

Comment: I try to load the url in chrome and it's the same, I can't reach my webserver... The network doesn't have internet connection does that change something ?

Comment: "You cannot use the http:// protocol unless you request clearTextTraffic in manifest file" what does that means ?

Comment: Then your problem has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: You do not need an internet connection for such a local ip like 192.168.4.1. What kind of server is running with that address on that device? What kind of device? The last .1 would indicate that it is a router.

Comment: Google for usesClearTextTraffic.

Comment: If I manually connect my phone on to the wifi network I reach the webserver in chrome, but if I fogot the wifi network and I connect the wifi network through my app I can't reach the webserver so the probleme is in the app. It's an ESP8266 with an embedded webserver

Comment: usesClearTextTraffic is already set on "True" in my manifest

Comment: Can your app reach the webserver if you manually connect your phone? You did not report this scenario.

Comment: Can Chrome reach the webserver if your app connects? You also did not report this scenario.

Comment: Manually connect : Chrome reach the webserver well / My app reach webserver well

Comment: Connect through my app : Chrome can't reach webserver / my app can't reach webserver

Comment: Ok. Now finally all is clear. I did not understand your post at all.

Comment: With android 10 the wifi connection as changed, so when I scan my Wifi QR Code a small window open and ask "Device to us with MyApp" and show the wifi network I wan't to connect, I have to confirm, then the wifi is connected but through the app. If I go in wifisettings I see i'm connected to the wifi network but it's write "Connected via MyApp" but when I'm connected via the app I can't reach my webserver. If I mannually connect to the wifi network it's write "Connected" and I can reach my webserver. What I don't understand is why when I connect wifi network via my app i can't reach webserver

Comment: Sorry, at the moment i cannot try your code.

Comment: Have you time to try my code please ? i'm stuck and I really need help.

Comment: I have no ESP8266 running. Is your problem for an esp only or for all routers/access points?

Comment: Your last picture has Connectiontype: cell instead of the first one who has Wi-Fi. Try in your code to set a connection type if possible.

Comment: The problem is for all routers/access points. Yes when I connect via my app it doesn't switch it's default route to wifi, how can I switch to wifi route ?

Comment: I dont know. What is this: setNetworkSpecifier(specifier) doing?

Comment: I try on another phone without sim card, same problem

Comment: Also answer my question please.

Comment: I found the solution ! Found it on a russian forum. Add this connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network); to use wifi connection and don't switch to cells connection even if there is no internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for help @blackapps

Comment: On a Russian forum! Great. I knew you were French ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution, just need to add a line that tell the app to bind the process to the wifi network you just connect.

```
connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
```

The final code :

```
public void successFlash(String ssid, String password) {

WifiNetworkSpecifier specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
        .setSsid(ssid)
        .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
        .build();

NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
        .build();

ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                openActivity_redirect_webview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnavailable() {
        // do failure processing here..
        openQrcodeActivity();
    }

};
connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback);
```

}

Comment: Hii emahrv. I am also having the same issue like wifi is connected but no network. i have also added that bindProcessToNetwork. but didn't work. can you please tell any other possibilities for this?

Comment: I am having the same issue. And this is not working for me

Comment: It seems that it's an issue that many devs are having, here is the Issue Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138335744